# StringProperty Struct and Class Kivy

Tags: python, class, kivy

I am having some troubles with my python code. I am new to classes and thererfor doesn't even know where the problem might be...
I am working with kivy and would like to send some data in a struct and this does only work for individual variables bit not in a struct:

```
class Counter_Timer(FloatLayout):
    for ii in range(len(client)):
        val[ii] = StringProperty() #becomes global variable
    val0 = StringProperty()        #stays local variable
    val1 = StringProperty()

    def update(self, dt):
        for ii in range(len(client)):
            result[ii]=readVal(client[ii])
        percVal = calcPerc(result)

        self.val0 = str("{:10.1f}".format(percVal[0])+'%') #works
        self.val1 = str("{:10.1f}".format(percVal[1])+'%') #works
        self.val[0] = self.val0                            #doesn't work
```

To be honest I don't even know why I need to assign StringProperty() to val0 and val1 for kivy, but it works. But it doesn't work for my for loop above in combination with the assignment in the last line of code. Maybe someone can help me!

Comment: `val` is a `List` instance? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1

> ```
> val0 = StringProperty()        #stays local variable
> val1 = StringProperty()
> ```
>
> why I need to assign StringProperty() to val0 and val1?

### Answer

You don't have to assign StringProperty() to val0 and val1.

## Question 2

```
self.val[0] = self.val0                            #doesn't work
```

### Answer

Since `val` is a Python List and declared as global, therefore you do not reference it as `self.val`. The keyword `self` references the “current widget instance”.  Kivy will look for an attribute, `val` defined at class level of *Counter_Timer* or defined/initialised in any of its methods.

Replace `self.val[0]` with `val[0]`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

val = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


class Counter_Timer(FloatLayout):

    for ii in range(10):
        val[ii] = StringProperty()  # becomes global variable
        print("\tva[{0}]={1}".format(ii, val[ii]))

    val = ListProperty([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Counter_Timer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("\ninit:")
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update, 1)

    def update(self, dt):
        print("\nupdate:")
        print("\tglobal variable - val:", val)
        print("\tlocal variable - self.val:", self.val)

        self.val0 = str("{:10.1f}".format(88.8)+'%') #works
        self.val1 = str("{:10.1f}".format(50.0)+'%') #works
        val[0] = self.val0
        self.val[0] = self.val0

        print("\tself.val0={0}, self.val1={1}".format(self.val0, self.val1))
        print("\tglobal variable - val:", val)
        print("\tlocal variable - self.val:", self.val)


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        print("\nbuild:")
        return Counter_Timer()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]